# Is there way to make links between files or directories on AEM-Assets?

Tags: aem

I use AEM6.2 Assets.

Is there way to make links between files or directories without programing? (like symbolic link)

I want to make "assets/B/photos" in the following.

```
assets/
├── A
│   └── photos
│       ├── 01.jpg
│       └── 02.jpg
└── B
    └── photos -> ../A/photos/
```

Comment: You may think of using subAssets for this.Sub-assets are assets that make up an asset, for example, layers in an Adobe Photoshop file or pages in a PDF file. In CQ DAM, you can manage sub-assets as you would assets.

Comment: Hi yash

I'd like to store the same files(or directory) in more than one folder.
But I'd like to store an original file in a folder and put symbolic link to the other folders.